# How to properly partition the incoming data using indexOf()?

Tags: java, processing, indexof, string-conversion

I created a graphical user interface using Processing 3.3.7 on my PC. A microcontroller is constantly publishing data in through COM8 in the form of

```
angle,distance.mindistance
```

followed by a new line. I wrote a simple code on the microcontroller which cycles through an array of data just to verify that the GUI is working properly.

The code that runs on Processing

1. reads the incoming data up to the new line character
2. finds the index of `","` and `"."`
3. assign whatever between position `"0"` and index of `","` to variable `angle`
4. assign whatever between index of `","` and index of `"."` to variable `distance`
5. assign whatever between index of `"."` and the end of the data to variable `mindistance`
6. do some further processing and visualize on the GUI.

**The problem is that `mindistance` is always assigned to 0, indicating a issue with step 5:**

See `void serialEvent (Serial myPort) {}`

**but `angle` and `distance` are displayed correctly.**

Relevant sections of my code are as follows:

```
import processing.serial.*; // imports library for serial communication
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent; // imports library for reading the data from the serial port
import java.io.IOException;

Serial myPort; // defines Object Serial

String angle="";
String distance="";
String mindistance = "";
String data="";
String noObject;
float pixsDistance, pixsMinDist;
int iAngle, iDistance, iMinDistance;
int index1=0;
int index2=0;
PFont orcFont;
int linefeed = 10; // new line ASCII = 10

void setup() {

  size (1600, 900);
  smooth();
  myPort = new Serial(this, "COM8", 115200); // starts the serial communication
  myPort.bufferUntil(linefeed); //reads the data from the serial port up to the character 'n'. So actually it reads this: angle,distance.mindistance
  orcFont = loadFont("OCRAExtended-30.vlw");
}

void serialEvent (Serial myPort) { // starts reading data from the Serial Port
  // reads the data from the Serial Port up to the character 'n' and puts it into the String variable "data".
  data = myPort.readStringUntil(linefeed);
  data = data.substring(0, data.length()-1);

  index1 = data.indexOf(","); // find the character ',' and puts it into the variable "index1"
  index2 = data.indexOf(".");  // https://processing.org/reference/String_indexOf_.html
  angle= data.substring(0, index1); // read the data from position "0" to to the index of "."
  distance= data.substring(index1+1, index2); // read the data between index of "," and index of "."
  mindistance = data.substring(index2+1, data.length()); // read the data from index of "." to the end of the data

  // converts the String variables into Integer
  iAngle = int(angle);
  iDistance = int(distance);
  iMinDistance = int(mindistance);
}

void drawObject() {// limiting the range to 400 cm
    // some more code here
}
```

**--- EDIT ---**

I found out that the `mindistance` is assigned with the right value (e.g. 40) but when the string is converted into an integer `iMinDistance = int(mindistance);`, `iMinDistance` becomes 0.

Comment: Can you please [break your problem down into smaller steps](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and then post a [mcve] of just a single step? Have you confirmed that your `data` variable is getting the correct value from your serial port? If so, eliminate all of that code and post a smaller example program that only includes your logic for breaking down the string, using a hard-coded value. Good luck.

Comment: @KevinWorkman please see my update. I think I made a better job diagnosing the issue this time.

Comment: That's a good start. can you please post a [mcve] that parses a hard-coded string and then prints out the resulting values? Sorry, I don't have a serial device so I can't run your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found out that the `mindistance` is assigned with the right value
>   (e.g. 40) but when the string is converted into an integer
>   `iMinDistance = int(mindistance);`, `iMinDistance` becomes 0.

This happens because the string assigned to `mindistance` is not an actually convertible to an int, i.e. it is probably followed by a space or new line. So one fewer index than the end of the data needs to be assigned to `mindistance`.

Change

```
mindistance = data.substring(index2+1, data.length());
```

with

```
mindistance = data.substring(index2+1, data.length()-1);
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what you already figured out, you might consider using the handy functions that Processing offers for string parsing.

For example, you could use the `splitTokens()` function to split your original string into individual values. You can learn more in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/splitTokens_.html), but here's a basic example:

```
String incomingString = "45,10.7";

String[] tokens = splitTokens(incomingString, ",.");
int angle = int(tokens[0]);
int distance = int(tokens[1]);
int minDistance = int(tokens[2]);

println("angle: " + angle);
println("distance: " + distance);
println("minDistance: " + minDistance);
```

(Side note: this is the kind of example program we talk about when we mention MCVEs.)

You could additionally use the `trim()` function to eliminate any extra whitespace characters:

```
String incomingString = "  45  ,   10   .   7   ";

String[] tokens = splitTokens(incomingString, ",.");
int angle = int(trim(tokens[0]));
int distance = int(trim(tokens[1]));
int minDistance = int(trim(tokens[2]));

println("angle: " + angle);
println("distance: " + distance);
println("minDistance: " + minDistance);
```

As always, [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/) is your best friend.